# Any portable bit trick to select the positive maximum of 2 numbers in C++98?

Tags: c++, templates, bit-manipulation

I have a function

```
template< class T>
T MaxMagnitudeOf2( const T a, const T b)
{
    T a = a<0? -a: a;
    T b = b<0? -b: b;
    return a>b? a: b;
}
```

Can it be implemented more efficiently **for all C++ basic types** (at least 16/32 bit types) using some bit trick?

Comment: Also, why *more* efficiently? The compiler should be able to optimize fairly good such a function. Did you measure that this function is a bottleneck?

Comment: It has to be profiled against another function (if an alternative exists). It is used inside a numeric comparison for a parallelity test.

Comment: @Ryan T is either "float, double, int, unsigned int, short, unsigned short".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about bit tricks, but you can reduce the number of comparisons from 3 to 2 like this:

```
template< class T>
T MaxMagnitudeOf2( const T a, const T b)
{
    return (a>b) ? std::max(a,-b) : std::max(-a,b);
}
```

Be sure to profile to check if there is any actual gain from this though, as there is a good chance that the compiler will avoid branches altogether for @rubenvb version (for built-in types, that is)

Comment: hei cool trick, well actually there's no measurable speed difference, but instruction count is lower.

Answer (score 5):

Don't overthink:

```
return std::max(std::abs(a), std::abs(b));
```

Make sure you include both `<cstdlib>` and `<cmath>` to get the integer and floating point overloads. Thank C for that detail.

Comment: available only in C++11 a correct abs also for integers

Comment: @Gamedeveloper there was only a problem for long long, the rest was already there.

Comment: nope, it is here but it cast integers to double u.u, the pure integer version that do not perform any cast is only in C++11

Comment: Prior to C++11, there was no problem for `long long` either, because the type `long long` itself didn't exist yet. @GameDeveloper Some overloads of `std::abs` are in `<cstdlib>`. Others are in `<cmath>`. Include both.